# popTOViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button named 'HOME'. In that button action I have the following code:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

When I click this button my app crashes.

Changing the index from 1 to 2, then it pops the view perfectly.

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

My view sequence is Page1 --> Page2 --> Page3

I want to go from Page3 to Page1 but the app crashes. From Page3 to Page2 it works fine.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try this.

Where I have written SeeMyScoresViewController you should write your View Controller class on which you have to go.(eg. Class of Home)

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
    id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[SeeMyScoresViewController class]]){
        [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: this make my app crash next time I click on the back button (on the SeeMyScoresViewController)

Answer (score 21):

If you want to go to the root viewcontroller (page1) just use:

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Also the first item in an index is not item 1 but item 0:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

This should bring you back to the first viewController, but it will them be easier to use the popToRootViewController method.

Comment: hey @rckoenes can you please reply to this similar question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546217/proper-way-to-call-poptoviewcontroller-ios

Answer (score 3):

Often it is more important to do that from top of stack, so:

In UINavigationController subclass or category:

```
- (void)popToLast:(Class)aClass
{
    for (int i=self.viewControllers.count-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        UIViewController *vc = self.viewControllers[i];
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:aClass])
        {
            [self popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and you call that

```
popToLast:[SomeViewController class];
```

Comment: to me that should be `[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES]`

Comment: @TonyTony It's custom UINavigationController subclass or category code in this example, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

An up-to-date way of popping back to a specific controller is:

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

MyViewController is the controller you want to pop back to.