# PopToViewController with modals

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, poptoviewcontroller

I am currently experimenting with PopToViewController and noticed that if I have the following scenario I get null back from the method:

Navigation Stack

UIViewController1 - position 0 
UIViewController2 
UIViewController3 
UIViewController4 
UIViewController5 presented Modally

I get an event triggering a pop back to UIViewController1.  When I call NavigationController.PopToViewController from UIViewController1, the return value is null but the views are removed from the navigation stack but the modal stays open.  I also don't appear to be getting any of the lifecycle events for the UIViewControllers that are removed.

Is this desired behaviour or documented anywhere? I can understand the modal remaining open but I don't get why the PopToViewController method would return null.

The ViewController I am popping back to is definitely in the Navigation Stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [popTOViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753256/poptoviewcontroller)

Comment: See this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753256/poptoviewcontroller/51420097#51420097